# How do I get cinnamon to display an icon for an executable?

Tags: cinnamon, icons, panel

I'm running an executable, `/usr/local/bin/myapp`, which is an X application. Unfortunately, on Cinnamon's taskbar, I don't get an icon for it - just a blank space. How can I make cinnamon (v5.2.7) display an icon of my choosing for it? I can get either a PNG, an SVG, or both.

Using Devuan GNU/Linux Daedalus, in case it matters.

Answer (score 0):

If the shortcut shows up here: /home/{USER}/.local/share/applications

Just add this line with a link path to an icon;

```
Icon=
```

If there is no file there for this app, just create one - copy the basics from another app there and replace with your app. This will then show up in the apps, eg. Start menu etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "shows up"? Also, should Icon be a full path name? A filename with extension? Just a base filename?

Comment: Icon=/home/{USER}/Pictures/IMAGE.png

When I say Shows up, what I mean is it appears in your Start Menu or list of Apps.